# When i write the script it shows TypeError: menuLi[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

This is my code

```
var menuLi=[];
$(window).load(function() {
var menuUl = document.getElementById("sub");                                          
menuLi = menuUl.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var len = menuUl.childNodes.length;

    nSpan = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var findUl;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        findUl = menuLi[i].getElementsByTagName("UL");
        liLen = findUl.length;
        if (liLen > 0) {
            menuLi[i].classList.add("myNew");
        }
    }
});
```

The above is my code which throws error menuLi[i] is undefined.

Comment: can you link the html code?

Comment: You are not considering `menuLi` length in the `loop`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

In fact you are looping using the wrong `length`.

**Explanation:**

Because the `menuLi.length` is lower than `menuUl.childNodes.length`, as `menuUl.childNodes` will contain all the `li` inside `menuUl` and their children.

So `menuUl.childNodes.length` is the number of `li` elements multiplied by the number of elements in each `li`.

So `i` will get greater than the `menuLi.length`, and that explains why you got `menuLi[i] is undefined`, because if you have only 5 `li` in `menuUl` and for example you are trying to get `menuLi[8]`, where `menuLi[8]` is `undefined`.

**Solution:**

So just use:

```
var len = menuLi.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping from `1` to `menuUl.childNodes.length` using `i`, but you are indexing straight into `menuUl[i]`.  Do you mean `menuUl.childNodes[i]`?